# problems using Parse in my app android

Tags: android, parse-platform, runtime-error

I am trying to use parse.com to send data to parse database as per their instructions using my following code. When I am trying to run the apk, and click on button it gives me this error: Unfortunately, Appname has stopped

What to do? What's my mistake? I even tried Try and catch with statements still doesn't work. 
What I want to send is textview.getText().toString() to "foo" in database

Here's my code:

```
TextView tv;
long ds;
TextView td;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;

public void onCreate() {
    Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bcapture);
    Button br = (Button) findViewById(R.id.brefresh);

    Button bs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsubmit);
    bs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
            testObject.put("foo", "td.getText().toString()");
            testObject.saveInBackground();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have not initialized your TextView. Furthermore `"td.getText().toString()"` should be `td.getText().toString()`.

If you still have trouble please post LogCat output in your question.

```
TextView tv;
long ds;
TextView td;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;

// not sure you ever call this either
// consider moving it to onCreate of Application http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/
//  public void onCreate() {
//    Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");
//  }

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bcapture);
    Button br = (Button) findViewById(R.id.brefresh);
    Button bs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsubmit);

    td = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview);

    bs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
            testObject.put("foo", td.getText().toString());
            testObject.saveInBackground();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a life saver. I forgot to call the function with ids in my oncreate. Thanks a lot again! :)

Comment: Oh and by the way, just a suggestion. Have a look at http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ makes it so much easier to deal with Buttons and Views in general (atleast I think)

Comment: Sure! I will have a look. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

@cYrixmorten this should work either way. 
I guess findViewById return null because you mistakenly used id from different layout. Code posted should work no matter if it makes sense. Did you check your ids?